# Best way to process RAW photos of acrylic paintings for print publication

Tags: lightroom, raw, publishing

Is any processing necessary on my RAW photos to prepare them for print (not Kindle) publication through KDP?

Besides any processing, the KDP requirements seem to be at least 300 DPI, highest resolution possible, not to compress the images, and no larger than 650 MB in size.  But which file format is best?

I have taken some RAW photos of some acrylic paintings to self-publish a tribute book.  First time with a camera, but the project is important to me.

Comment: I’m afraid this question my be so broad as to be unanswerable.

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: 300 DPI alone is meaning less. What are the print size of the pictures? The combination of the two tells you what should be the minimum size in pixels, which is the only thing that counts.

Comment: The trim size of the book will be 8.25" x 11" (20.96 x 27.94 cm).  I expect one to four photos per page,  Some of the paintings are 5" x 5" while most are 30" x 40" and everything in between.

Comment: @E2R0NS Can we assume when you shot these photos that you altered the focal length and/or subject distance in order to fill, or almost fill, the shorter dimension of the camera's sensor, regardless of the actual size of the painting?

Comment: Will photos be printed all the way to the edges of the page, or will there be a margin reserved with the maximum photo size somewhat smaller than the trim size? Will the book be landscape (11" wide) or portrait (11" tall)? Are most of the paintings taller than wide (portrait) or wider than tall (landscape)?

Comment: @MichaelC I zoomed in as close as I could for each photo, but the camera was always 42" from the painting.  Margins.  Portrait sized book.  Most of the paintings are portrait shaped, but not all.

Comment: Do you have a link to the KDP requirements?

Comment: @MichaelC There is no image info for hardcovers, but here is the info for paperbacks: https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G202169030

Comment: While the instructions there will lead to the intended results, whoever wrote that doesn't have a clue about the difference between dots (a drop of ink) and pixels (a unit of a digital image). It takes many dots of ink to print a single pixel. Part of the problem is that the original EXIF standard labeled the near meaningless *pixels per inch* field as *dots per inch* and the error has persisted and been embellished endlessly. My next question, though, is will there be significant text in this book as well? If not I wouldn't imagine why anyone would want to use Word to format a photo book!

Comment: Note: Back in the dark ages of dot-matrix pin printers, where a pin struck the special paper with enough force to release embedded monochromatic ink to the surface of the paper (or with enough force to transfer dye from a sheet of "carbon paper" in between two sheets onto one of the sheets) a dot and a pixel were the same thing. But with the advent of color inkjet printers a large number of ink droplets (dots) are needed to produce a single pixel.

Comment: The KDP instructions do not say to not compress the files (all JPEGs are compressed to one degree or another). Instead, it says to not let Word further recompress the files again when they are inserted into the Word document.

Comment: @MichaelC There will be no text at all except for an opening paragraph or two.